# App Storing Data in iCloud

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cloudkit

I submitted my app update for approval to the App Store, and apparently I'm storing 6.47 MB on the user's iCloud.

I have no idea what this could come from, so I could use some help.

Here's the message I received from Apple: From Apple
0. 3.0 BEFORE YOU SUBMIT: ICLOUD
Before you Submit

On launch and content download, your app stores 6.47MB on the user's iCloud, which does not comply with the iOS Data Storage Guidelines.

The iCloud attributes on my app are: key-value storage and CloudKit. I use CloudKit to store App information and download it from the cloud upon launch. I save information locally, I'm pretty sure.

Any suggestions on what this could come from?

Here's my save function:

```
func saveFacts() {
    let isSuccessfulSave = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(birdFacts, toFile: BirdFact.ArchiveURL.path!)
    if !isSuccessfulSave {
        print("Failed to save bird facts")
    }
    else {
        print("saved bird facts")
    }
}
```

Comment: Presumably nothing you store on the private Cloudkit database is this size? What type of stuff are you downloading from CloudKit upon launch and how are you storing that locally?

Comment: I'm downloading lots of "facts". Each fact includes a few strings, a picture, and a NSDate.

Comment: In terms of storing locally, I'm saving the facts using NSCoding

Comment: What are you then doing with the NSCoding results - saving to files? If so I suspect that is your problem, as those files may be being backed up to iCloud as user data, with the images being the main memory hog.

Comment: Yes, that's my intention. I added the function where I was saving things to my original question

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing information in local files they may be subject to backup to the user's iCloud, which could be the source.

You can avoid them being backed-up by moving them to a different location in the sandbox or using the NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey attribute.

See [Make App Backups More Efficient (Apple)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTips/PerformanceTips.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW17).

For example code in Objectice C and Swift using NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey see [How do I prevent files from being backed up to iCloud and iTunes?(Apple)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1719/_index.html)

Comment: How do I add that attribute to the things I am saving?